# Use functional React component to create file upload with submit button

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Apologies for any misunderstandings as I'm very new to React. It should be noted that I'm using Typescript with strict null checking. I'm trying to create a functional component with a file upload that has a submit button, so you select file -> see file name and submit button -> click submit to actually upload. I've tried using State Hooks but can't get the built-in ones to work with the File object that can be gotten from `e.target.files[0]`.
Here's what I have:

```
return(
      <Row>
        <Col>
          <div className="input-group">
            <div className="input-group-prepend">
              <span className="input-group-text" onClick={(e) => fileSelected && handleUploadClick(e)}>
                Upload
              </span>
            </div>
            <div className="custom-file">
              <input
                type="file"
                className="custom-file-input"
                ref={fileInput}
                onClick={handleFileSelect}
              />
              <label className="custom-file-label">
                {(fileSelected && selectedFilename) || "Select a file to upload"}
              </label>
            </div>
          </div>
        </Col>
      </Row>
    );
```

Answer (score 0):

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
let imageFile = null; const handleFileSelect = (e)=> { imageFile = e.target.files[0] console.log(imageFile) }
<input type="file" className="custom-file-input" onClick={(e)=>handleFileSelect(e)} />
```

Comment: you should have your handleFileSelect function similar to what I just posted, have a variable declared on the global scope and then change its value in the handleFileSelect function to equal e.target.files[0] and remember to pass the handleFileSelect function to onclick event listener the way I did and u should be fine